# Minimal basis for set of binary vectors using XOR

Tags: complexity-theory, arithmetic, matrices, linear-algebra

I would be surprised if this isn't a well-studied problem, but I'm not sure what else to search for at this point: you're given a set of binary $n$-vectors $S \subset \{0,1\}^n$. The problem is to find another set of binary $n$-vectors $B \subset \{0,1\}^n$, with minimal size $|B|$, such that every vector in $S$ can be expressed by the XOR results of some subset of $B$ (so $B$ is essentially a basis for $S$ using XOR instead of addition and allowing only binary coefficients in the linear combination).

In a way, this is a form of [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) for binary vectors. While searching for literature on this problem, I came across the [Discrete Basis Problem](http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~pmiettin/papers/dbp.pdf) also discussed in [this PhD thesis](https://helda.helsinki.fi/bitstream/handle/10138/21376/matrixde.pdf), which seems closely related. Instead of XOR it uses OR, and here $|B|$ is an additional input (and the task is it to minimise the error in representing $S$ with vectors from $B$). This problem is NP-hard. Does the same apply to the problem I've presented above, or is there an efficient solution? Any pointers to existing literature would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you treat your vectors as over the field $GF(2)$ rather than over the set $\{0,1\}$, then what you ask is to find a basis for the span of a set of vectors. This is a well-studied problem in linear algebra, which you probably know the solution for. (One option is Gaussian elimination.)

Comment: That's a great opportunity to brush up your linear algebra.

Comment: Thanks for making me facepalm pretty hard. It's really obvious now... ;)